# Uib Pagination - how to get the value of the clicked element and prevent scroll to top

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using uib pagination for my project. I managed to get it to scroll to top when i clicked on the link. But how i can prevent scroll to top when i click on the '...'

I have attached the image of my pagination and html.
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1dNm.png)

```
<ul ng-show="$ctrl.projects.length > 10" boundary-link-numbers="true" rotate="false" max-size="4" previous-text="&lsaquo;" next-text="&rsaquo;" ng-change="$ctrl.pageChanged()" uib-pagination total-items="$ctrl.projects.length" ng-model="$ctrl.currentPage" items-per-page="$ctrl.projectSize"></ul>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-model contains the value of the clicked element